# How can I make a Magento Page completely blank?

Tags: php, html, api, magento

I'm trying to create a custom Magento page for my module that is completely blank with only one string in the output. The page cannot have HTML tags like `<html>`, `<body>` and `<head>`.

I need this to make a API integration with Facebook, which scrap the page content to check if a string is valid, so I can't have any HTML code, only pure plain text.

Code so far:
Controller:

```
public function facebookAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

View:

```
<?php
$action = $this->getRequest()->getActionName();
echo Mage::getModel('chatbot/chatdata')->requestHandler($action);
?>
```

Now it's showing the string I want, but with HTML tags. If I remove the loadLayout and renderLayout, then it shows nothing.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154974/create-completely-empty-page-in-magento-1-9-2-4

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for your feedback, but sadly that dosen't work for me, because Magento adds HTML tags to the page, like <html>, <body>, <head> etc.

Comment: Show us what you've tried already please.

Comment: Have you created a Magento extension? If so, in the controller you can simply not return anything, so for instance your controller action would be `public function indexController() { }` Or if not, you'd need to hook into a handle, you could then use local.xml to set a blank template on the reference "root", but I think you'd need the extension to get the unique handle.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I've updated the question with the current code I have. @PhilS I'm using a custom module, but doind that didn't worked.

Comment: I think this question should belong on http://magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: It's possible that you need to send a header like `Content-type: text/plain`. Without the HTML body tags, it probably doesn't qualify as valid HTML, so it might be misleading to allow that header to be sent. If your layout is including HTML it is because you've defined wrapper blocks, etc that include them. Worst case scenario, you can output content directly from your controller if you need to.

Comment: Despite what the others are saying, I don't believe this question is too broad, or off topic for Stackoverflow. It provides a good amount of background information and code to be able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: No worries, you can also call a different template from your controller action using `$this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->setTemplate('page/yourtemplate.phtml');` after `loadLayout()` and before `renderLayout()`, I don't know what you're model is outputting, but setting the template on root would remove the default layout for that node so you could then have what you liked.

Comment: It's not ideal, but could you simply die() with your output in the controller action? - also, be sure to check the source code, and not rely on developer tools, as that will likely add extra syntax that isn't there.

Comment: @Phils, it worked!! Could you post that as a official answer so I can upvote it?

Comment: Great, glad it worked.

Comment: Thanks @PhilS, and thanks all of you who tried to help me. Have a nice coding day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call a different template from your controller action using

```
public function facebookAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->setTemplate('page/your‌template.phtml');
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

This overwrites the "root" node from your layout XML and replaces it with your own template.

Answer (score 1):

you can remove diffrent section from your custom page using xml like this.

```
<reference name="root">
    <remove name="header"/>
    <remove name="content"/>
    <remove name="footer"/>
</reference>
```

Then you can add your custom code in your phtml file.

Comment: Thanks, that actually works visually, but the HTML code it's still in there.

Comment: You can try your code using this, because now it not load any default content of the magento.

Comment: My current code is: `<remove name="head" />
  <remove name="right" />
  <remove name="left" />
  <remove name="header" />
  <remove name="footer" />` and still didn't worked.

Comment: Have you set your custom page layout to "Empty" as well.